# Why submit text direction with "dirname" attribute

Tags: html, forms

Why submit the text direction with the "dirname" input attribute?

Source:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_dirname.asp

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="myText" dirname="myText.dir">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</from>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<input>` element is extensively used in the creation of HTML forms. Using the `dirname` attribute with the `input` tag instructs the user agent to include text-direction info with its form-submission. Text-direction will be indicated by one of two possible results: `ltr` (left-to-right), or `rtl` (right-to-left).

Here is a list of languages that are written from `rtl` (right-to-left):

- Arabic
- Aramaic
- Azeri
- Dhivehi/Maldivian
- Hebrew
- Kurdish (Sorani)
- Persian/Farsi
- Urdu

Unless organizations want people's names (and other information) showing up spelled backward in their database, they require some way of knowing text-direction for each form-submission they get.